# what is magic number to find whether OS on disk present and is it same for all archetectures & devices.Or is it bootloader 2 decide what it should be

Tags: linux, bootloader, bios, grub

I was trying to study bootloader and OS and bios do. So

I found this link
https://dev.to/frosnerd/writing-my-own-boot-loader-3mld

which lead to a lengthy tutorial from a university professor. from the tutorial I read that The way bootloader/bios (these two terms are used interchangbly by the writer I think) differentiates to find executable of OS and data and things is by using loop and check for a thing called magic number which is stored once in every disk at specific address location. Magic number is `0xaa55`. So  it means that its written in the hard disk(s). so let say I have two or three OS installed and at boot option I can select which one to boot from. where the magic number stored of second OS if I only had one hardware disk device but multiple partitions. as the boot sector magic number location for only disk is taken by first OS magic number: present at Cylinder 0, Head 0, Sector 0.  Since I can make partition ,divided the disk into multiple parts let say Linux-A and Linux-B partitions.  The author says

```
So, the easiest place for BIOS to find our OS is in the first sector of one of the              
disks (i.e. Cylinder 0, Head 0, Sector 0),
...
 an unsophisticated means is adopted here by BIOS, whereby the last two
 bytes of an intended boot sector must be set to the magic number 0xaa55
```

the above led me to think that magic number may be one for every disk but not anymore after concept of disk partition there may be some other number too . I like know how OS starting address is found if there are multiple OSes and single disk with multiple partitions

also is 0xaa55 considering without partitions on same disk is it same for all CPU architectures(is 0xaa55 is magic number for both x86 and x86-64) and hard disks dependent? Or it a bios or bootloader dependent. like if someone makes own bootloader or edit `grub` code then one can consider any number as magic number let say 0xabcd. what thing defines the number 0xaa55 magic number should be 0xaa55.

Comment: 0xAA55 is the magic number (actually last 2 bytes) of an MBR (Master Boot Record).  GPT, VTOC and other partition schemes do not use this magic number. Nothing to do with an OS.

Comment: @fpmurphy - Really? GPT has a protective MBR in it and I always thought that 0xAA55 was the thing that BIOS was looking for, whatever the partition scheme might be.

Comment: @Vilx-A GPT-partitoned disk under a certain size has a protective MBR sector.

Comment: @fpmurphy `GPT, VTOC and other partition schemes do not use this magic number.` first thanks for ur comment. if GPT, VTOC and other schemes dont use it then do they maintain in some OS level number or technique which boot-loader  is always oblivious about this since its OS level, if yes then How they are even maintained cant the second OS data on same system override the first OS scheme maintained data. or bootloader knows about partitions this is the question.

Comment: The interaction between an OS and a bootloader isn't standardized. Every bootloader must know every OS it intends to load, so that it would know _how_ to load it. And there is no way for a bootloader to find installed OSes on a sytem. That's why you have to write a big complicated config file for grub so that it knows where to find and how to load each OS on your system. Sure, you might use some tricks to auto-detect some of them, but those are just tricks specific to each OS, not some universal standard.

Comment: I just remembered that in the olden days there was a way in a MBR-style partition table to mark a partition as "bootable" And the default (DOS?) bootloader would then perform the same trick that the BIOS did - load the first sector of that partition, check for magic bytes, and execute it. In essence, you got a bootloader that loaded another bootloader. But I don't think this scheme is used much these days anymore. At the very least, you couldn't give names or have menus - it just loaded the first one it could find.

Comment: @Vilx do u do linux embedded development too besides doing windows

Comment: @user786 - Nope, never done any kind of embedded stuff. And although my backend code does run on Linux, I've never done anything low-level or Linux-specific. :D All this stuff is just something I've picked up along the way. And I'm not entirely certain about it, so better double-check my words.

Comment: @fpmurphy FROM THE LINK IN MY QUESTION: `The next section focuses on writing the boot loader related files (mbr.asm, disk.asm, gdt.asm, and switch-to-32bit.asm). Afterwards we will write the kernel and the entry file....` this means `boot loader related files (mbr.asm, disk.asm, gdt.asm, and switch-to-32bit.asm)` part of bootloader and u said `0xAA55 is the magic number (actually last 2 bytes) of an MBR (Master Boot Record). ` continue reading connected next comment

Comment: so MBR is part of bootloader u said but what I read is a magic number is at the start of OS(so its a part of OS).  which one is correct. Please clarify

Comment: I would say that `0xAA55` is neither a part of the bootloader, nor the OS. It's a marker in the first sector of the drive that tells the BIOS - "Hey! These 512 bytes contain executable code which will somehow boot the OS". MBR is a particular way of describing partitions on the disk (GPT is another alternative, but there are others). The MBR standard accommodates for the fact that some bytes in the first sector will need to be set aside for executable code and the marker.

Comment: When you're writing both your own OS and bootloader, the line between them becomes quite blurry. The bootloader - if you can call it that - basically exists only to get around the size limitation of that first sector. You can't fit your entire OS in 512 bytes. So you make something that can start the whole thing and pull up the rest from the disk. Maybe you'll need to do it in a few steps because 512 bytes might not even be enough to load your entire OS. But where the bootloader ends and OS starts - that's quite arbitrary.

Comment: Ahh, I think I see where the confusion comes from. The guy in the article basically defines MBR in his code. I see this as more of a practical compromise or maybe a hack. When he compiles his program, he will have ready-made 512 bytes to write to the 1st sector of the drive, `0xAA55` and all. Probably his code will occupy the next sectors too (I didn't read that far). This is just to make life simpler and easier. This doesn't mean that "MBR is part of the bootloader". Just that they have to share the same sector on the disk, so you gotta combine them somehow...

Comment: @Vilx- yes this is also the comment. But look at this link this is very clearly states number oof things https://www.cs.bham.ac.uk/~exr/lectures/opsys/10_11/lectures/os-dev.pdf

Comment: @user786 - I'll read that later, have to go now. Which place in particular is confusing?

Comment: @user786 That PDF assumes the old PC boot mechanism, i.e. classical BIOS, one disk marked as bootable, read sector zero (MBR) of that disk, find bootable partition using the MBR, and then jump to offset zero of that partition and execute code. Modern PCs use UEFI which implements a completely different boot mechanism.

Answer (score 2):

My own understanding of these things is a bit rough as well, but hopefully I'll be able to shed a little light that will enable you to continue on your path. If anyone can correct errors in my text, I'd be happy!

Firstly, BIOS and bootloader aren't the same thing. BIOS is a bunch of code that is stored in a special chip on your motherboard (you can update this code with "BIOS updates" from your motherboard manufacturer). When your computer is turned on, the motherboard loads this code in RAM and then sets the CPU to start executing it. It's literally the first code that runs when your computer is turned on.

After BIOS has performed its work and initialized the hardware it needs to initialize, it starts to look for the OS to boot. It does this by going around and interrogating various devices until it finds one that can boot. Modern BIOSes can boot from a variety of devices, like hard drives, USB drives, floppy drives, CDs, network adapters, RAID controllers and possibly other exotic things.

For each of these devices the interrogation process varies, but for hard drives the BIOS looks for the magic bytes you've mentioned at a pre-determined location. In fact, what BIOS does is it loads the first 512 bytes of the drive in memory (it used to be that all hard drives had 512 byte sectors, so in the olden days this would have been 1 sector) and then checks for the magic bytes. If it finds them, it sets the CPU to execute the first (I think) byte of that sector and that's where it's job ends.

Now these first 512 bytes are the bootloader. Actually, 512 bytes isn't very much. In fact, if you have a MBR-style partition scheme, you have even less than that, because the whole partition table has to fit in there too. It's definitely NOT enough bytes to show a prompt to the user or do nearly anything else useful. Sure, if you're writing your own bootloader that might be enough, but for modern bootloaders it's not even close. So all that those 512 bytes do is load MORE code from somewhere else in the hard drive. And that code quite possibly load more code from elsewhere, etc. And eventually you've loaded enough data in the RAM to have a full-featured bootloader that can present prompts to the user, show splash screens and whatnot else.

What the bootloader then does and how it loads an OS is quite specific to the particular OS, so this is where the commonalities end. If there are multiple OSes on the system, the bootloader needs to know about them too, and how it does that also differs wildly from bootloader to bootloader. You can make your own scheme.

Now, a note about compatibility. This whole scheme is the "IBM PC BIOS" scheme. It was first used in the IBM PCs, but they became so wildly popular that everyone started to make their own "IBM PC Compatible" machines and thus they also had to include a BIOS that worked the same.

You see, in those early days the operating systems were very simple. The concept of "drivers" didn't exist yet and the BIOS filled its space. Since it knew the hardware it would be run on (PC customization wasn't nearly where it is today), it could also include some code that knew how to deal with that hardware. So, even when BIOS gives control over to the bootloader, it still leaves a bunch of code in memory in pre-determined locations, which the bootloader (and later the OS and programs) can use to interact with the hardware. Things like reading and writing to disks, showing stuff on the screen, sending data over serial/parallel ports, etc.

Now, modern OSes don't care about it anymore. They have their own drivers and they interact with hardware through their own code, so the leftover code from BIOS is useless to them. But since compatibility is such an important thing, all the BIOSes even into modern age had to emulate these aging standards. Even more, they had to initialize all the hardware while booting - something that a modern OS would redo anyway, so it was just wasted effort.

Because of this and other inefficiencies, the UEFI standard was born. It replaces the BIOS and... it's quite complicated and I don't really know how it works anymore. What I do know that the OS can actually load special drivers into the UEFI (or vice versa?) so that the hardware initialization work isn't wasted. It can also check the digital signature of the bootloader to prevent malicious code and other things. This results in a much faster boot process, but also all that stuff about magic bytes and whatnot else goes flying out the window. I don't really know how UEFI switches over to the bootloader.

And also, yes - this is all specific to the PC space. I don't know how Mac computers work. It's also quite possible that the new M1 macs do things differently. And other kinds of devices like smartphones and embedded systems have entirely different boot schemes too.

P.S. Just in case, about MBR vs GPT - you really don't need a disk partitioned with either of them. They are just two standards that most OS manufacturers have agreed upon so that they can use each others disks. But it's just a convention. BIOS doesn't care how your disk is laid out. It just cares about the first sector. As long as your bootloader and your OS can understand and work with your custom fancy scheme, everything is good. Except that I think UEFI *did* require the disk to be formatted as GPT, since it actually read some more data from it... but I'm not sure. BIOS definitely doesn't care.

Comment: `what is BIOS updates` what is updates: is it software or hardware. do I need any special device to update bios. How to connect that special device to bios chip. Can u show some image. The bios hardware as I know is small round shaped in black color container and inside it its bios chip on my motherboard. There are no opening to bios chip's black round container on motherboard. How can I update bios with bios updates? I believe kernel coders and embedded developers live with these things that's what they do.

Comment: @user786 - Huh? You've never done that? Just go to the webpage of your motherboard's manufacturer, find your precise motherboard model, and in the "Downloads" section there usually is "BIOS updates" or maybe "Firmware updates". The code in the BIOS chip can be updated via software. It's just a piece of flash memory these days. You download a little app, run it, and the BIOS code gets updated. It's that simple.

Comment: `After BIOS has performed its work and initialized the hardware it needs to initialize, it starts to look for the OS to boot` from bios to kernel really this is directly. Where is the bootloader which suppose to be in the middle of bios and kernel. Bootloader like grub loads kernel. How come bios doing this. What bootloader does then?

Comment: @user786 - Mind you, not every motherboard has a bios update. They only release them when there is something noteworthy to fix in the old BIOS code. Sometimes it's all good and there are no updates.

Comment: @user786 - `Where is the bootloader which suppose to be in the middle of bios and kernel?`  - That's what is in those first 512 bytes. The bootloader. The BIOS loads the bootloader and then the bootloader loads the OS kernel. Mind you, the BIOS doesn't know and doesn't care about any of this. It just loads the 512 bytes and sets them to execute, that's it. Whatever is in there - kernel, bootloader, pixies and unicorns - is not BIOS's problem.

Comment: @user786 - Also, this whole "bootloader" business is a modern invention, and merely a convention. A bootloader really is like a "mini-operating-system" with just one job - load another operating system. How it does that is... well, not standardized. You can do whatever you like.

Comment: ` The code in the BIOS chip can be updated via software. It's just a piece of flash memory these days. You download a little app, run it, and the BIOS code gets updated.` wow I am surprised thanks for this info. So means that a userspace software can update bios chip memory which u said is flash memory and that's it. That's cool. And all this time I thought these low level hardware and userspace had strong firewall between them. That's very informative thanks for this. I still have one comment about can u please take a look. Thank for this info its priceless :)

Comment: @user786 - Well, I'm not entirely sure if any user-space application can do it, or it needs some support from drivers in kernel-space. But, fundametally, yes. Whatever safeguards there are, will be at the OS level, not in hardware. Although these days the hardware _might_ check for digital signatures of the new code. That would make sense.

Comment: @user786 - Btw - you might be surprised, but other pieces of hardware in your computer also might have firmware updates available the same way. Things like hard drives, DVD drives, video adapters, etc. They're much rarer, but they do exist.

Comment: @user786 - "I still have one comment about can u please take a look. " - which one do you mean? I think I've answered all.

Comment: @Vilx- Bootloaders are not a modern invention as you claim.  Every OS requires some form of a bootloader to bootstrap the OS.  Been that way since computers were first developed.

Comment: @fpmurphy - Well, I suppose that's true. I meant "bootloader as we today know them" - a whole software suite with advanced configuration, capable of user interaction etc. The early bootloaders were quite minimalistic and dual-booting was unheard of. At this stage I'm hesitant to call them "bootloaders" and trying to draw a clear line between a bootloader and OS proper.

Answer (score 0):

On a Mac M1, open the terminal and run system_profiler